# how to save data in android activity life cycle method

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

i am currently working on an app.In my app i use a autocomplete text view where i have not set the autocompletetextview adapter initially.The idea is that users will enter their first data normally and for that no suggestions will be shown but after press the save button then the adapter will be set and then if they try to enter the same data it will show the suggestion.i complete this part.but my problem is when i return to the home screen or press back or home screen button all of my data is lost.help me and advance tnx. By using a database i hope the problem will be solve but i want to keep it simple and do not want to use database.is there any other way..

```
package com.example.oggy.autocompletetextviewsuggestion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AutoCompleteTextView textView;
    String[] array;

   ArrayList <String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oncreate 
    is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplite);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        array = 
   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_name);

        // when screen is rotating i can retrive  data 
  successfully
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "execuiting saveinstance part" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            myList2=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("value");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size :" +myList2.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList2);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList1);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //saving data by pressing the button and save it in my list and also set the autocomplite textview adapter
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // String[] series = {"abang","bang"};
                // array1[i]=textView.getText().toString();
                myList.add(textView.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item :" + textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data :" + array1[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        });



    }
//save the list view while screen is roatating
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        myList1 = myList;
        outState.putStringArrayList("value",myList1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onstop is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ondistroy is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onrestart is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onstart is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onresume is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onpause is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: you can save strings in csv format in onStop() and load it back in onStart()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save data locally use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference), that allows you to permanently save key-value pairs.

Here's a simple way to use that (quoting from the link above).

### Get `SharedPreferences` instance

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

### Write to it

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("SavedHighScore", newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

### Read from it

```
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt("SavedHighScore", myDefaultValue);
```

### Write list

It is not possible to add a List of String, but you can add a `Set<String>` using [putStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html). Let's say you have one `ArrayList<String>` you can write it to the SharedPreferences this way:

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<> {{/*  ....  */}};
Set<String> mSet = new HashSet<String>(mList);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("MyStringSetKey", mSet);
editor.commit();
```

### Read list

```
Set<String> defValues = new HashSet<String>();
/* Initialize your default value set with your default values,
   eventually empty or null */
Set<String> storedValues = sharedPref.getStringSet("MyStringSetKey", defValues);
/* Now you have a set containing your strings
   if you want you can convert it to ArrayList or whatever this way */
ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>(storedValues);
```

### PS

In the examples I hardcoded the key string. Easier for the example but you have to avoid it in real code. Always use string resources.

Comment: Tommaso Pado i want to save a array list not a single string..can u suggest me hoe to save array list while i press the back button or home screen button..

Comment: I edited my post with the answer, check last section.

Comment: Tommaso padi can u tell me how can I retrieve my list from shared preference i mean give me the read code and tnx bro

Comment: you are welcome, post edited, check "Read list" section

Answer (score 0):

To save data to another **Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToRetrieve.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE");//String data
startActivity(intent);
```

Then **retrieve** the data inside `onCreate()`

`String theData = getIntent.getExtras().getString("KEY");`

Comment: i want to save a array list not a single string..can u suggest me how to save array list while i press the back button or home screen button..